# How to have a separate navi on desktop vs mobile?

Tags: css

1. I am using this template as a base for my portfolio, https://html5up.net/phantom

Currently, there is a hamburger navigation in both web and mobile.  How can I make it so that hamburger menu only shows on mobile? I tried changing the     @media screen and (max-width: 736px) { to 480 for the menu CSS but it doesn't change anything..?

2. Also is there a way to change the pink hover of the menu?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, but kinda works.

- Set burger menu to display: block;
- then have @media only screen and (min-width: width that you want) and inside you set burger menu to display: none;
  That means that from the width you set in the media queries it won't display the menu.

Hover you can simply change easy. Just find in the code where the :hover has the property color:; set to pink - and in your code override it with targeting the element and adding :hover and then adding the color you want it to be.

Comment: I combed through the entire document and can't find the pink,

Comment: I found this though:

#menu > .close:before {
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3E%3Cstyle%3Eline %7B stroke-width: 8px%3B stroke: %23f2849e%3B %7D%3C/style%3E%3Cline x1='15' y1='15' x2='85' y2='85' /%3E%3Cline x1='85' y1='15' x2='15' y2='85' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    opacity: 0;
   }

Answer (score 0):

```css
/*use*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 736px){

      /*then put the hamburger class here*/



}
```